# Unable to connect to MongoDB, Error Message

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, web

I am trying to connect to Mongo Db my code is as follows;

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// //for testing
// app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//   res.send("api is working");
// });

//database connect
// tourbooking tour1992

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
const connect = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    console.log("MongoDB database connected");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection failed");
  }
};

// middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server listening on port", port);
});
```

Output is showing as follows;

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
server listening on port 4000
```

But not connected to the server message is not displayed, and console has the following errors:

Please help with the above code issue ? Again I am a toddler in Coding Many thanks for the help in advance

Comment: `console.log(err)`

Comment: What error message? In any case, it doesn't look like you are calling your `connect()` function at all?

Comment: GET http://localhost:4000/ 404 (Not Found), this is what I am getting in console.log

Comment: @rajee You need to uncomment `app.get("/"` handler. As currently you do not provide any endpoint handler

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `connect` method and declare the route:

```
// //for testing
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.send("api is working");
});

// middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connected");

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server listening on port", port);
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection failed");
});
```